# solving database configuration

Tags: php, proxy

We have a Database running on a server. We need to know if this DB is running or not at any given time. The status of the DB could be ‘Active’ or ‘Down’.
We have two Proxy servers that report on the status of DB, but there is an odd problem with one of the Proxy servers! one of the Proxy servers appear to ALWAYS Lie !! but we don't know which Proxy server is lying. We don't have access to the source code to look into the problem and we need to know about the correct status of the DB. we also cannot call to DB directly because of security restrictions.

DB api returns a json string when asked for status:
example:
{“Status”: “Down”}
Proxy servers are supposed to return whatever data DB is passing to them. as mentioned before one of Proxy server modifies the value of status for no known reason.

The only thing we can configure is the DB status API endpoint address on the Proxy servers.

what is the solution so we can always be sure of the status of the DB server ?

Thanks.

Comment: If you have to communicate only with the proxies, and you hav no control over how the proxies work, then there is nothing you can do? Unless you can somehow ask the proxy not to modify any of the JSON and just return it all?

Comment: ok what is return it all ?

Comment: Whatever the database server returns to the proxy